# jquery templates php с переменными ${}

Tags: jquery, шаблоны

Создан jquery шаблон в который AJAX-ом и PHP выводятся данные:

```
<select name="market">
    <?php
        if(!empty($markets)):
    ?>
    <option value="">Торговый центр</option>
    <?php
        echo '${market_id}';
        foreach($markets as $market):
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$market['market_id']?>" <?=  ($market['market_id']=='${market_id}' ? 'selected' : '')?>><?=$market['name']?></option>
    <?php
            endforeach;
        else:
    ?>
    <option disabled>Нет торговых центров</option>
    <?php
        endif;
    ?>
</select>
```

Попытался вывести текущий айди AJAX-ом `${market_id}` и вставил в PHP код, как видно выше. Конечно же он не сработал. Как правильно скрестить PHP и переменные из AJAX в jquery шаблоне?

`type="text/x-jquery-tmpl` — это тип шаблона.

Comment: Постарайтесь понять как это всё работает вместе - PHP отдает конечный код клиенту, а на клиенте происходит обработка данных и их рендеринг через jQuery шаблоны. Что именно вы пытаетесь сделать в вашем коде? Если код выше находится в серверном файле, что вам с ним нужно сделать?

Comment: `${market_id} === $market_id` + `Notice: undefined constant, string assumed`

Comment: Нечетко заданный вопрос, непонятно что надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй сделать так:

```
'`${market_id}`'
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: проблема была в построении переменной. '${market_id}' вывело